# Running "wc -l <filename>" within Python Code

Tags: python

I want to do 10-fold cross-validation  for huge files ( running into hundreds of thousands of lines each). I want to do a "wc -l " each time i start reading a file, then generate random numbers a fixed number of times, each time writing that line number into a separate file . I am using this:

```
import os 
for i in files:
    os.system("wc -l <insert filename>").
```

How do I insert the file name there. Its a variable. I went through the documentation but they mostly list out `ls` commands, something that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: FYI, google says 1 lakh == 100 000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import subprocess
for f in files:
    subprocess.call(['wc', '-l', f])
```

Also have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions - for example, if you want to access the output in a string, you'll want to use `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `subprocess.call()`

Comment: And this also gives me an error. Says this : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../scripts/gps_scripts/cross-validation.py", line 10, in <module>
    print subprocess.call(['wc','-l',f])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1213, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Comment: @crazyaboutliv You passed it a file _object_ instead of a file _name_.

Comment: one-liner to get the file line count in Python: `int(subprocess.check_output(["wc", "-l", fname]).decode("utf8").split()[0])`

Comment: -@sudo, your one-liner works great on my windows 7 box, but does not work on windows 10.  I get FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.  Yet I can see the file clearly exists.

Comment: sudo's answer should be included in the correct one.

Answer (score 15):

Let's compare:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def wc(filename):
    return int(check_output(["wc", "-l", filename]).split()[0])

def native(filename):
    c = 0
    with open(filename) as file:
        while True:
            chunk = file.read(10 ** 7)
            if chunk == "":
                return c
            c += chunk.count("\n")

def iterate(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            pass
        return i + 1
```

Go go timeit function!

```
from timeit import timeit
from sys import argv

filename = argv[1]

def testwc():
    wc(filename)

def testnative():
    native(filename)

def testiterate():
    iterate(filename)

print "wc", timeit(testwc, number=10)
print "native", timeit(testnative, number=10)
print "iterate", timeit(testiterate, number=10)
```

Result:

```
wc 1.25185894966
native 2.47028398514
iterate 2.40715694427
```

So, wc is about twice as fast on a 150 MB compressed files with ~500 000 linebreaks, which is what I tested on. **However**, testing on a file generated with `seq 3000000 >bigfile`, I get these numbers:

```
wc 0.425990104675
native 0.400163888931
iterate 3.10369205475
```

Hey look, python FTW! However, using longer lines (~70 chars):

```
wc 1.60881590843
native 3.24313092232
iterate 4.92839002609
```

So conclusion: it depends, but wc seems to be the best bet allround.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `wc -l` Use the following python function

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
            pass
    return i
```

This is probably more efficient than calling an external utility (that loop over the input in a similar fashion).

**Update**

Dead wrong, `wc -l` is *a lot* faster!

```
seq 10000000 > huge_file

$ time wc -l huge_file 
10000000 huge_file

real    0m0.267s
user    0m0.110s
sys 0m0.010s

$ time ./p.py 
10000000

real    0m1.583s
user    0m1.040s
sys 0m0.060s
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the file it might be faster to use `wc` since it's written in C.

Comment: @ThiefMaster true, it's all about knowing your input

Comment: Yes,  my files are 30 lakh lines. I was thinking that counting this way would get slower .

Answer (score 3):

`os.system` gets a string.  Just build the string explicitly:

```
import os 
for i in files:
    os.system("wc -l " + i)
```

Comment: "Execute the command (a string) in a subshell." - I smell security holes if the file list comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: I agree, but `os.system` is a gaping security hole to begin with, for precisely that reason.

Comment: Guys, I need to keep this in deployment. This goes straight into production . Do you guys suggest then to stick to enumerate, even though it would take a tad longer ?

Comment: This is giving me an error btw :(  . Here : wc: invalid option -- 'g'
Try `wc --help' for more information.
256
wc: invalid option -- 'g'
Try `wc --help' for more information.
256
wc: invalid option -- 'g'
Try `wc --help' for more information.
256
<repeat this another 10-12 times> [ The code is same as written above>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python approach I found to solve this problem:

```
count_of_lines_in_any_textFile = sum(1 for l in open('any_textFile.txt'))
```

Comment: I don't close the file here, do you? Or will Python garbage collector do that for you?

Comment: This causes a StopIteration error if you are using an enumeration method afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I found a much more simple way:

```
import os
linux_shell='more /etc/hosts|wc -l'
linux_shell_result=os.popen(linux_shell).read()
print(linux_shell_result)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to the “native” function by lazyr:

```
import functools

def file_len2(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        lines= 0
        reader= functools.partial(f.read, 131072)
        for datum in iter(reader, ''):
            lines+= datum.count('\n')
            last_wasnt_nl= datum[-1] != '\n'
        return lines + last_wasnt_nl
```

This, unlike `wc`, considers a final line *not* ending with '\n' as a separate line. If one wants the same functionality as wc, then it can be (quite unpythonically :) written as:

```
import functools as ft, itertools as it, operator as op

def file_len3(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        reader= ft.partial(f.read, 131072)
        counter= op.methodcaller('count', '\n')
        return sum(it.imap(counter, iter(reader, '')))
```

with comparable times to `wc` in all test files I produced.

NB: this applies to Windows and POSIX machines. Old MacOS used '\r' as line-end characters.