# How to build a numpy array row by row in a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

This is basically what I am trying to do:

```
array = np.array()       #initialize the array. This is where the error code described below is thrown

for i in xrange(?):   #in the full version of this code, this loop goes through the length of a file. I won't know the length until I go through it. The point of the question is to see if you can build the array without knowing its exact size beforehand
    A = random.randint(0,10)
    B = random.randint(0,10)
    C = random.randint(0,10)
    D = random.randint(0,10)
    row = [A,B,C,D]
array[i:]= row        # this is supposed to add a row to the array with A,C,B,D as column values
```

This code doesn't work. First of all it complains: TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found. But I don't know the final size of the array.

Second, I know that last line is incorrect but I am not sure how to call this in python/numpy. So how can I do this?

Comment: How about `array = np.empty((4,?))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A numpy array must be created with a fixed size.  You can create a small one (e.g., one row) and then append rows one at a time, but that will be inefficient.  There is no way to efficiently grow a numpy array gradually to an undetermined size.  You need to decide ahead of time what size you want it to be, or accept that your code will be inefficient.  Depending on the format of your data, you can possibly use something like [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or various functions in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to read it in.

Comment: hmm so if there is preprocessing, does it make more sense to do that all and build 1 big cvs or text file with the processed and then use numpy.fromfile vs building it step by step?

Comment: The other common `numpy` approach is to collect the 'rows' in a list, and pass that to `np.array` or `np.concatenate` at the end.  That's what `loadtxt` does.

Comment: If you don't need to load the file you can just read its number of lines using [**subprocess**] and [**wc -l**] 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520761/running-wc-l-filename-within-python-code]

Answer (score 4):

Use a list of 1D numpy arrays, or a list of lists, and then convert it to a numpy 2D array (or use more nesting and get more dimensions if you need to).

```
import numpy as np

a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append(np.array([1,2,3])) # or a.append([1,2,3])
a = np.asarray(a) # a list of 1D arrays (or lists) becomes a 2D array

print(a.shape)
print(a)
```