# To count total number of rows in a csv/.txt file and write it to a new csv file in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I want to count the total number of rows in a csv file/.txt, output/write it to a new csv file, then clean the file and write a 2nd column to the new file with total number of rows after cleaning. ( I currently have the code for cleaning, I only need help with accepting a file and writing the total rows to a new file before and after cleaning) I have attached the code below which writes only the column name to a new csv file and doesn't print the result.

```
import csv
data = open ('/anusha.csv','r') 
#numline = len(file.readlines(data))
#print(numline)
before_clean = []
with open('out_anusha.csv', 'w') as f1:
    for row in data:
        f1 = len(file.readlines(data))
        before_clean.append(f1)
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    f1.write("Before_clean")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to count number of lines in file without going through whole reading process is to use wc utility if this program is supposed to run on *nix system.

You can refer [Running "wc -l <filename>" within Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520761/running-wc-l-filename-within-python-code)