# How can I periodically skip rows reading txt with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to process data measured every 20 seconds during the whole 2018 year, the raw file has following structure:

date time a lot of trash

in several rows

amount of samples trash again

data

date time a lot of trash

etc.

I want to make one pandas dataframe of it or at least one dataframe per every block (its size is coded as amount of samples) of data saving the time of measurement.

How can I ignore all other data trash? I know that it is written periodically (period = amount of samples), but:
 - I don't know how many strings are in file
 - I don't want to use explicit method file.getline() in cycle, because it would work just endlessly (especially in python) and I have no enough computing power to use it

Is there any method to skip rows periodically in pandas or another lib? Or how else can I resolve it?

There is an example of my data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OefLwpTaytL7L3WFqtnxg0mDXAljc56p/view?usp=sharing

I want to get dataframe similar to datatable on the pic + additional column with date-time without technical rows

Comment: have you looked at the `skiprows`  argument in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: I have, you must have the list of indexes to skip to use it, and the only way to know it all is to count in cycle, what means (because I don't know how to count lines without reading them all, this question is over here also) I need to read all my data with  file.getline()

Did I miss smt?

Comment: Did me and RafealC understand your question correctly?

Comment: Oh, not sure, I try one more: I need to skip 5 rows, read 56, skip 5 and so on. I can't use reading line by line in a cycle because of a size of my data and I don't know how else I can get information about how many rows are in file. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), where `N` below means `read every N lines`

```
from itertools import islice

N = 3
sep = ','

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    lines_gen = islice(f, None, None, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame([x.strip().split(sep) for x in lines_gen])
```

Comment: Thank you, looks closely but it's not exactly what I need - I need to read 56 lines, then skip 5 and then read 56 lines again and so on. So step can't help me to deal with that

Comment: @Alexandra just read every 61 rows and slice until index `-5`, i.e. `[:-5]`

Comment: Seems I understood the problem: I need to get not only one sixty-first row (or every sixty-first rows), but the whole sixty one rows :) It is not about a single row. Sorry for bad expression

Answer (score 0):

I repeated your data three times. It sounds like you need every 4th row (not starting at 0) because that is where your data lies. In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for `skipsrows` it says.

> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x: x in [0, 2].

So what if we pass a `not in` to the `lambda` function? that is what I am doing below.
I am creating a list of the values i *want* to keep. and passing the `not in` to the `skiprows` argument. In English, skip all the rows that are not every 4th line.

```
import pandas as pd

# creating a list of all the 4th row indexes. If you need more than 1 million, just up the range number
list_of_rows_to_keep = list(range(0,1000000))[3::4]

# passing this list to the lambda function using not in.
df = pd.read_csv(r'PATH_To_CSV.csv', skiprows=lambda x: x not in list_of_rows_to_keep)
df.head()

#output
0  data
1  data
2  data
```

Comment: The problem was I didn't know the highest limit (1 million in your example), but I have used wc -l ubuntu command to get it from every file in the beginning of preprocessing and just count thrashy rows numbers in cycle :)
So I think I should close the question, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just count how many lines are in file and put the list of them (may it calls useless_rows) which are supposed to be skiped in pandas.read_csv(..., skiprows=useless_rows).

My problem was a chip rows counting.
There are few ways to do it:

1. On Linux command "wc -l" (here is an instruction how to put it into your code: [Running "wc -l <filename>" within Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520761/running-wc-l-filename-within-python-code))
2. Generators. I have a key in my relevant rows: it is in last column. Not really informative, but rescue for me. So I can count string with it, appears it's abour 500000 lines and it took 0.00011 to count

   ```
   with open(filename) as f:
       for row in f:
           if '2147483647' in row:
               continue
           yield row
   ```